# CloudWatch Dashboards: Override time window

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I have a CloudWatch dashboard showing a bunch of important metrics for the past 12 hours.

I'd like to monitor my Emails and SMS consumption. Therefore I need a widget showing the sum of all the SES outbound emails and all the SNS Text Messages requested since the first day of the current month - despite of the Dashboard time window being the past 12 hours.

[image: 12 hours period]

With Grafana, I was able to override the time window for one widget - but I can't find a such feature in CloudWatch. How can I do that ?

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a way to do this?